# 64-bit Unsigned Integer concat benchmarking

Tags: performance, go, benchmarking

I have a tweak question. I had some repetitive pieces of code in my web-app requests where simple things like `fmt.Sprintf("%d%d", 01293123, 234993923)` happens.

Now I did some benchmarks and tested a bytes writer, which was quite slow (~400 ns/op). The `sprintf` itself was about 240 ns/op. Then I did strings joining:

```
var concatBuffStr []byte

func BenchmarkStringsJoin(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        concatBuffStr = []byte(strings.Join([]string{
            strconv.Itoa(2),
            strconv.Itoa(3),
        }, " "))
    }
}

152 ns/op
```

A big improvement already. But then I tried clunking 2 ints converted to bytes together

```
var concatBuffStr []byte

func BenchmarkConcatIntsAsBytes(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        aBuf := make([]byte, 8)
        bBuf := make([]byte, 8)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(aBuf, uint64(2))
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(bBuf, uint64(3))
        concatBuffStr = append(aBuf, bBuf...)
    }
}

57.8 ns/op
```

Amazing! But I could just avoid glueing them together and already reserve the full 16 bytes for 2 maxed out 64 bit uints spaces:

```
var concatBuffStr []byte

func BenchmarkCopyIntsAsBytes(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        concatBuffStr = make([]byte, 16)
        bBuf := make([]byte, 8)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(concatBuffStr, uint64(123123))
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(bBuf, uint64(3453455))
        copy(concatBuffStr[8:], bBuf)
    }
}

30.4 ns/op
```

By now we're 8 times faster than with the `fmt.Sprintf()` method.

Was wondering if there is an even faster way than this. I want to avoid `unsafe` tho.

I was also thinking of checking the max value of both 2 ints and if they are below the MAX of an `uint32` or `uint16` I could customize the logic. Benchmarking the `uint16` downgrade by hand is around `23 ns/op`, but that's not realistic as in the web-request itself it would still need to check the size of the ints and do extra logic, which will likely result in more overhead than that `7 ns/op` gain.

**Update**

I managed to simplify it a little bit more:

```
var concatBuffStr []byte

func BenchmarkCopyIntsAsBytesShort(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        concatBuffStr = make([]byte, 16)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(concatBuffStr, uint64(123123))
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(concatBuffStr[8:], uint64(3453455))
    }
}

28.6 ns/op
```

Comment: Your `binary` approaches don’t do the same thing as the original. Does that mean the format is flexible and you just need to store two integers together in some number of bytes?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. You started with a string output, then started packing bits. What exactly is it that you want this function to spit out?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It's used for a data caching key that needs to store 2 integers as keys to identify their combined uniqueness. An older version was even `fmt.Sprintf("%d_%d")`, but that didn't seem necessary anymore.

Comment: For clarification. The cache-key is a `[]byte`, which is currently wrapped around the `fmt.Sprintf()`. I figured reserving the max of 2 int64 (Database Pkey Ints) and putting them in their own 8 bytes part would be just as valid. Please correct me if I'm wrong tho.

Comment: You've made it all the way down to the smallest building blocks of the integers. I'm not sure this can really run any quicker. It's cool to see how things evolved as they did. Thanks for sharing, but I don't think I can help :)

Comment: That's ok :) Thanks for the response tho! Even tho this tweak seems small it upped my `wrk` `req/sec` from `~43500` to ~`44250`. Because Go is so insanely fast, these tweaks that might look so small significantly contribute to lighter calls, making it easier and easier to run fast sites on light servers for small customers :)

Comment: Well, good thing you’re moving away from `%d%d` then, because that makes (1000, 10) and (10001, 0) produce the same result.

Comment: In your real code, are you writing to a global? Making `concatBuffStr` local might be faster.

Comment: Try https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#AppendInt on a empty buffer but with large enough _capacity_ so that no allocations happen. This will probably be the fastest.

Comment: The buffer has to be local as it's unique per request of the web-app. The original code was with the underscore in between so that was safe. The actual stated `%d%d` was already when starting the optimisation :). strconv.AppendInt sadly doesn't work correctly as it won't reserve the correct bytes for both parts.